# How to use ng-if with angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-translate

I'm writting a mobile app using Ionic framework, also I'm using angular-translate, and its working nice, but I want to display content in English or Spanish depending on user language selection. I'm trying to use ng-if to validate the condition, this is part of my code:

```
      <div  class="tit" ng-if=" {{'LANGUAGE' | translate}} == en ">
         {{adult.desdeAct}} - {{adult.titleAct}}
  </div>
     </div>
     <div  class="tit" ng-if=" 'LANGUAGE' | translate == sp ">
        <div  class="tit">
         {{adult.desdeAct}} - {{adult.titleActEs}}
  </div>
     </div>
```

But the ng-if is not woking, I mean is not validating the expresion.
Does anybody can give me a tip please?

Regards,
caribesoft

Answer (score 1):

That's not really how you're supposed to use translations. The idea is to have one piece of HTML code, and have key/value dictionaries for the languages you want to support:

Base on their [docs guide](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide), you'll have something like:

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    'LANGUAGE': 'Hello'
  });

  $translateProvider.translations('sp', {
    'LANGUAGE': 'Hola'
  });

  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);
```

Now after you've set values for `LANGUAGE`, you can do this:

```
<div  class="tit">
    {{'LANGUAGE' | translate}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Omri, in all my app I'm doing the things as you comment, but in this section of the app is more complicated, In my post I mentioned that will be a text in english or spanish, but the thing I want to display here is the content of the fields of Firebase database, the problem is that for English I named "titleAct'" and for spanish I named "titleAct'Es", so this is my problem, how do I display  for English : <div  class="tit">
      {{adult.desdeAct}} - {{adult.titleAct}}
  </div> and for spanish <div  class="tit">
         {{adult.desdeAct}} - {{adult.titleActEs}}
   </div>

Comment: @CaribeSoft In that case that you named your variables differently (maybe see if you can change it?) I don't think you have any other choice, but you can still use one HTML and call a function in your controller and have a switch case there to return the desired text.

Comment: Hi Omri, is not variable names, area database collection field names, these has to b e different, one field for english and another for spanish. And the problem is how to retrive the correct depending on the language selected,

Answer (score 0):

I have also made an app in two language: English & Greek, And I used a different way to switch between languages. Instead of having ng-if for language swith you can have it in this way.

Use `{{'KEYTEXT' | translate}}` for the text inside the div, and in the translation table add these keys and their value.

AS,

```
<div  class="tit" >
      <1--here will be Text -->
      {{'KEYTEXT' | translate}}
 </div>
```

And in your ENGLISH translation table

```
{
 "KEYTEXT" : 'English Text'
}
```

And in your Spanish translation table

```
{
 "KEYTEXT" : 'Spanish Text'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a Global variable and assign value to it such as "en" or "sp" depending upon your user selection and then display the language according to the choice accordingly like:

```
if(user selects spanish) {
     GlobalVariable = "sp";
     $translateProvider.preferredLanguage(GlobalVariable);
}

<div  class="tit" ng-if="GlobalVariable == 'sp' ">
          {{{{'LANGUAGE' | translate}} }}
     </div>
```

u can also look at **@Omri Aharon** answer for better understanding.